# Is there a way to have a delay in between code in p5.js

Tags: p5.js, mit-scratch

So I want to have a delay  in my Draw function so that when I want to do

```
Xoffset = Xoffset + 1.5
```

I do not go from 0 to 30 in a secnd, but I want there to be some delay in the code so that I can easily manage it. I usually use scratch and if you are unfimiliar to that the command for a code delay is

```
Wait(Insert amount of seconds you want to delay here)
```

So when you start a part of the code, and the Wait is set to 2, the input will go off, wait 2 seconds, and then move on the the line of code below. I am trying to replicate that but in p5.js.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417937/create-a-simple-countdown-in-processing/12421641#12421641) , there's a p5.js example at the bottom. Out of curiosity, what's the connection between p5.js and mit-scratch for your problem ?

Comment: Have you tried using `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 3):

To detail my comment above, you could do something like this:

```js
var xOffset = 0;

// time delay vars
// current time "snapshot" (imagine pressing the lap time button)
var time;
// the interval to wait between time "snapshots": 2s (2000 milliseconds) in this case
var wait = 2000;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
  
  //store the current time
  time = millis();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  //check if the difference between now and the previously stored time
  // is greater than the wait interval
  if(millis() - time >= wait){
    console.log(wait, "ms passed");
    //if it is, do something
    xOffset = xOffset + 1.5;
    //also update the stored time
    time = millis();
  }
  
  circle(xOffset, 150, 60);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure what the main purpose of the delay is:

1. is it to slow things down for debugging purposes
2. is to go into a series a states (e.g. ball moves up for 2s, then right
   2s, etc.),
3. is to animate/smoothly interpolate between two positions within a given
   time ?

Maybe something else completely ?

If you simply want to slow things down, perhaps it might be simpler to adjust the [`frameRate()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate):

```js
var xOffset = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
  
  // update 1 frame every two seconds => 0.5 fps
  frameRate(0.5);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  xOffset = xOffset + 1.5;
  
  circle(xOffset, 150, 60);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Processing still has a [`delay()`](https://processing.org/reference/delay_.html) function, but p5.js doesn't.
Personally I'm not a fan of blocking behaviour like this and prefer the `millis()` options even though it's more verbose. That being said, if the program/demo you write is super simple `delay()` might just be enough.

Even if `delay()` is missing you could use js [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) with a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but that's getting into more advanced JS as Paul already mentioned:

```js
var xOffset = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(300, 300);
  // prevent p5's default draw() updates
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  xOffset = xOffset + 1.5;
  
  circle(xOffset, 150, 60);
  
  // wait 2s then call draw() manually
  delay(2000).then(draw);
}

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Now, if you want to create a smooth animation from a start x offset to an end offset in a set amount of seconds you'd need a different approach.
You can find a p5.js example at the of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820062/processing-making-a-draw-method-slowly/5821506#5821506):

```js
var startTime;
var duration = 2000;
var startValue = 0;
var endValue = 300;
var currentValue = startValue;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(300, 300);
  textAlign(RIGHT);
  startTime = millis();
}
function draw(){
  background(255);
  moveCircle();
  drawCircle();
}
function drawCircle() {  
 circle(currentValue, 150, 60);
}

function moveCircle(){
  var progress = (float)(millis()-startTime)/duration;//millis()-startTime = difference in time from start until now
  if(progress < 1.0) currentValue = startValue + (endValue * progress);//the current value is the final value scaled/multiplied by the ratio between the current duration of the update and the total duration
}
function mousePressed(){//reset value and time
  currentValue = startValue;
  startTime = millis();
}
function keyPressed(){//update duration
  if(key == '-') if(duration > 0) duration -= 100;
  if(key == '=' || key == '+') duration += 100;
  console.log("duration: " + duration);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

And if you're comfortable using external libraries you could simply use a tweening library such as [gsap](https://greensock.com/get-started/):

```js
var x = 0;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(300, 300);
  // animate "this" global object's x property to 300 in 2 seconds
  gsap.to(this, {x: 300, duration: 2});
}

function draw(){
  background(255);
  circle(x, 150, 60);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.8.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the animation has a bit of easing (default ease out) which could be nice.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, unlike Scratch, there is not a *good* way to delay *synchronous** code. The reason for this is that all the functionality of a webpage is run using a single thread. Which means that while there can be multiple sequences of instructions performing different pieces of functionality, only one of those sequences can execute at a time. Therefore if you did something to delay the execution of JavaScript within the `draw()` function, it would block all other functionality, making the browser tab unresponsive (and potentially causing the browser to halt your JavaScript altogether).

Instead of pausing a series of JavaScript statements like one would do in Scratch, it is necessary to either use the amount of time that has elapsed as part of a condition that determines whether some code should run (which is what [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417937/create-a-simple-countdown-in-processing/12421641#12421641) George shared in the comments does), or to use the built in [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function to schedule some code to run some number of milliseconds in the future (but you would not want to call `setTimeout()` from `draw()` because it would repeatedly schedule the code every frame).

** note: there are also ways to create delays using asynchronous javascript code, but this is a more advanced topic*